# Sieve of Eratosthenes using a Javascript array

Tags: javascript, sieve-of-eratosthenes

Any feedback on my code would be greatly appreciated.

```
/* 
   The Sieve of Eratosthenes using a javascript array as
   an associative data structure.
*/

function range(start, limit, step) {
    var rangeArray = [];
    for (var i = start; i < limit; i += step)
        rangeArray.push(i);
    return rangeArray;
}

function isNotNull(value) { // predicate for filtering
    if (value !== null)
        return true;
    else
    return false;
}

function nullMultiples(multiple, array) { // mutates array
    var step = multiple;
    while (multiple < array.length) {
        array[multiple] = null;
        multiple = multiple + step;
    }
}

function nextPrime(currentPrime, array) {
    var successor = currentPrime++;
    while (array[successor] === null)
        successor++;
    return successor;
}

function primes(below) {
   var initSet = range(0, below, 1);
   var primeSet = []; // set of numbers used as a multiple
   var currentPrime = initSet[2]; // the first multiple is 2
   while (currentPrime < Math.sqrt(initSet.length)) {
       primeSet.push(currentPrime);
       nullMultiples(currentPrime, initSet); // mutate initSet
       currentPrime = nextPrime(currentPrime, initSet); 
   }
   // return the numbers that were used as multiples and all
   // inidicies that still contain a number, except 0 and 1
   return primeSet.concat(initSet.slice(2).filter(isNotNull));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're just doing steps of `1` and starting with `0`, we don't need to take account for those. Your `range` function can be simplified into the following.

```
function range(length){
  return Array.apply(null, Array(length)).map(function (_, i) {return i;});
}
```

Also, a comparison is already a boolean by itself. So your `isNotNull` could be simplified into the following. We could coerce `value` into a boolean by using `!!`, since we're working with numbers, we might encounter `0` which is falsy but technically not null. So we compare explicitly with `null` instead to avoid this.

```
function isNotNull(value) {
    return value !== null;
}
```

You could also inline your search for the next prime into your `primes` function. You can simply check your number list if the next number has been nulled, and if so, have the loop in `primes` skip the number.

With that (and hopefully my understanding of the algorithm isn't wrong), here's my take:

```js
function range(length) {
  return Array.apply(null, Array(length)).map(function(_, i) { return i; });
}

function getPrimes(end) {

  // We get the numbers below the square root of the limit. The | 0 is 
  // dropping the decimal info, and since range here is zero-indexed,
  // we add 1.
  return range((Math.sqrt(end) | 0) + 1).reduce(function(numbers, root, index) {

    // If the number at root is null, then its multiples may have been
    // nulled by an earlier prime. We bail out. Nothing to do here.
    if (numbers[root] === null) return numbers;

    // We null every multiple, provided it's not 0 and 1
    else if (root !== 0 && root !== 1)
      for (var i = root * root; i < numbers.length; i += root)
        numbers[i] = null;

    // If we reached here, then probably you're looking at 0 or 1
    else numbers[root] = null;

    return numbers;

    // Here's the array that generates 0-to-end. Again, range is
    // zero-indexed so the + 1 is necessary.
  }, range(end + 1)).filter(function(i) {

    // Since 0 and 1 are already nulled, they will fall off here. No
    // additional slicing needed.
    return i !== null;
  });
}

document.write(getPrimes(121).join(','));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your thoughtful answer. I'm sorry I didn't get back to you. After becoming familiar with Clojure here's what I've come up with:

Comment: `function primesLessThan(n) {
    var composites = range(3, Math.sqrt(n), 2)
    .map(function(x) {
     return range(x * x, n, x);
 })
    .reduce(concat);
    var data = [2].concat(range(3, n, 2));
    return data.filter(doesNotContain(composites));
}

function range(start, end, step) {
    var result = [];
    for(var i = start; i < end; i += step)
 result.push(i);
    return result;
}


function concat(a, b) {
    return a.concat(b);
}

function doesNotContain(arr) {
    return function(elem) {
 return !(arr.indexOf(elem) > -1);
    };
}`

Comment: Here's a link to it (https://github.com/thomasvarney723/prime-numbers/blob/master/non-recursive.js). I think it's readable but is cripplingly slow compared to both yours and my first attempt.